# How do i give a non root user access to docker when using docker-dind?

Tags: docker, go-cd, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to run a Go CD agent using docker-dind to auto build some of my docker images.

I'm having trouble getting the user `go` to have access to the docker daemon.

When I try and access docker info I get the following:

```
[go] Task: /bin/sh ./builder.shtook: 2.820s
[START]
[USER]  go
[TAG]  manual

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/containers/fish/angular-cli/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB

Step 1/8 : FROM node:8-alpine
 ---> 4db2697ce114
Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER jack@fish.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 22f46bf6b4c1
Step 3/8 : VOLUME /usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86b979e7a2b4
Step 4/8 : RUN apk add --no-cache --update build-base python
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a08b0a1fc9d
Step 5/8 : RUN yarn global add @angular/cli@1.5.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fe4530181a5
Step 6/8 : EXPOSE 4200
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 480edc47696e
Step 7/8 : COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 329f9eaa5c76
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb1180ff8e9f
Successfully built cb1180ff8e9f
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/containers/fish/angular-cli/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

My `root` user *can* accesss docker info properly, but the `go` user fails.

```
$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:root
bin:x:1:root,bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:root,bin,daemon
sys:x:3:root,bin,adm
....
adm:x:4:root,adm,daemon
wheel:x:10:root
xfs:x:33:xfs
ping:x:999:
nogroup:x:65533:
nobody:x:65534:
dockremap:x:101:dockremap,go
go:x:1000:go
```

My docker.sock permissions are as follows:

```
$ ls -alh /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----    1 root     993            0 Apr 20  2017 /var/run/docker.sock
```

What do I need to append to my Dockerfile in order to allow the `go` user to access the docker daemon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running a `dind` container, IE docker in docker, it its common place to volume mount `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` from the host into the dind-container.

When this occurs, the PID is not only owned by root, but by a numeric group id from the host.

Running the following inside the container should show you the host GID:

```
$ ls -alh /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----    1 root     993            0 Apr 20  2017 /var/run/docker.sock
```

The above process is owned by group 993, 993 is derived from the host machines /etc/group -> docker role.

As it is nearly impossible to ensure that we have a common group id when the image is first built, the group id should be assigned at runtime using your `docker-entrypoint.sh` file.

My personal goal is to get this runtime user of 'go' for a GO CD go-agent, but one could substitute this approach for jenkins or any other runtime user.

As the dind & go-agent are both based off alpine linux, the following will work for alpine-linux:

```
#setup docker group based on hosts mount gid
echo "Adding hosts GID to docker system group"
# this only works if the docker group does not already exist
DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_GROUP=docker
BUILD_USER=go

if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
    DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})

    #addgroup is distribution specific

    addgroup -S -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
    addgroup  ${BUILD_USER} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
fi
```

If you exec into the container, and cat your /etc/group file, you should see the following:

```
docker:x:993:go
```

Comment: will this work if the container is run as a non root user, because entrypoint is then run with non root permissions?

Comment: For the `addgroup -S -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}` line, I get the error: `addgroup: gid '999' in use`

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified version of @Jack's answer.

I created a `docker-entrypoint.sh` which will determine the GID and reuse the group if it already exists.  Primarily on Docker for Windows machines the Docker socket is using `root`.  This would need `runuser` as `su` will only work if the user's shell is not set to `nologin` which in my case is set to `nologin`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
RUNUSER=jobberuser

if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
    DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})
    DOCKER_GROUP=$(getent group ${DOCKER_GID} | awk -F ":" '{ print $1 }')
    if [ $DOCKER_GROUP ]
    then
        addgroup $RUNUSER $DOCKER_GROUP
    else
        addgroup -S -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker
        addgroup $RUNUSER docker
    fi
fi
exec runuser -u $RUNUSER -- $@
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow other users to access Docker you need to:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker go
```

If you are running this command as the `go` user, you need to logout and login after performing above task.

Comment: Not quite - looks like the docker.sock file is still owned by a 'host' group 993. How do i get the groupIDs to match?